# Adding a feature id when writing to file

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

for creating Tilesets with tippicanoe, i retrieve spacial data from postgis and write it to a .geojson file with geopandas:

````
geodata = gpd.read_postgis("test", engine1, geom_col='geom')```
geodata.to_file("test.geojson", driver='GeoJSON')
````

my question is: Is there a buildin method or convinient way to add featureIDs to all features in a featurecollection? I would need an output as shown below, having the id set at feature level, not in the properties.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "atco_code": "300000492FZ",
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": (-1.1372773238238423, 52.346655194010665),
            },
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "atco_code": "0600CR19133",
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": (-2.518177475249135, 53.063122731640604),
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

My current workflow is to write the file to .geojson, reading it again, injecting the ids and saving it again. Which is very unconvinient!

```
with open("test.geojson") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)
for i in range(0,len(gj["features"])):
    gj["features"][i]["id"] = gj["features"][i]["properties"]["id"]
with open("test.geojson", 'w') as outfile:
    geojson.dump(gj, outfile)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Comment: When someone answered your question, what should you do -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geodata.__geo_interface__` to get a python feature collection. [document](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.__geo_interface__.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.__geo_interface__)

Sample geodataframe:

```
        name  id                                               geom
0  polygon A   1  MULTIPOLYGON (((36.00000 11.00000, 36.00000 12...
1  polygon B   2  MULTIPOLYGON (((36.50000 11.50000, 37.50000 11...
2  polygon C   3  MULTIPOLYGON (((36.61799 10.80580, 36.61570 11...
```

The result generated from the geodataframe:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'id': '0',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'id': 1, 'name': 'polygon A'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
    'coordinates': [(((36.0, 11.0),
       (36.0, 12.0),
       (37.0, 12.0),
       (37.0, 11.0),
       (36.0, 11.0)),)]},
   'bbox': (36.0, 11.0, 37.0, 12.0)},
  {'id': '1',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'id': 2, 'name': 'polygon B'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
    'coordinates': [(((36.5, 11.5),
       (37.5, 11.5),
       (37.5, 11.0),
       (36.5, 11.0),
       (36.5, 11.5)),)]},
   'bbox': (36.5, 11.0, 37.5, 11.5)},
  {'id': '2',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'id': 3, 'name': 'polygon C'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
    'coordinates': [(((36.61799, 10.8058),
       (36.6157, 11.19321),
       (36.86327, 11.29637),
       (37.34925, 10.91813),
       (37.0054, 10.71182),
       (36.61799, 10.8058)),)]},
   'bbox': (36.6157, 10.71182, 37.34925, 11.29637)}],
 'bbox': (36.0, 10.71182, 37.5, 12.0)}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just used this. A couple of refinements: I believe is same/similar to geodata.to_json().... 

  with open('test.geojson', 'w') as f:
    f.write(geodata.to_json())

Also, the ids will be strings so tippecanoe will need to be warned with --convert-stringified-ids-to-numbers